# Bind Entity Framework DbSet object to DevExpres xtrareports

Tags: c#, devexpress, datasource, xtrareport

I am trying to bind an entity framework DbSet to DevExpress XtraReports, but I get only one row in the generated PDF inctead of the whole dataset.

I used the following code:

```py
var report = new MyReport();

var ds = myDbContext.Students.ToList();
report.DataSource = ds;
```

I tried to use simple queries it works, but I do need to use my EF linq statements, instead of filling my code with static queries.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: firstly check the ds.Count under the debugger. secondly, check the XtraReport.DataMember value - i think the right value should be an empty string. you can share the report layout (in the vs designer click on top-left smarttag and select "Save..." action) or even share project to demonstrate your trouble.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by setting the ValueMember property to null instead of empty string.

Comment: if this is a real story, so we can post a bug to XtraReports, you can share the project